# Неправильные локаторы XPath (Selenium)

Tags: selenium, xpath

Даны неправильные локаторы XPath (Selenium). Подскажите что в них неправильно?

```
"//tr[contains(@class,'table-row')]//td(14)//span"
"//a[contains(@class,'ui-datepicker')]/span[text='Next']"
"//div/input[@id="UserName\"]"
"//div/input[@id='UserName' || @name='Username']"
"//div[@id='property_Date']/following-sibling:div[@class='trigger']"
```

Comment: кем даны и кто сказал, что они неправильные? ;) [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: в тесте даны и написано что все неправильные и нужно их исправить. Ошибка в синтаксисе